# jaxb with existing classes and schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to map existing xml schema to existing java classes?

I have several xml schemas and I need to map them all to one java class. Xml files differs a bit in way of storing data.
E.g.

```
public class DataStorage {
   public String data1;
   public String data2;
   public String data3;
}
```

and set of different xml files

```
<?xml ...?>
<dataCase1>
<data1>...</data1>
<data2>...</data2>
<data3>...</data3>
</dataCase1>

<?xml ...?>
<dataCase2>
<data data1="..." data2="..." data3="..." />
</dataCase2>

<?xml ...?>
<dataCase3>
<data>
<innerData>
<data1>...</data1>
</innerData>
<otherData data2="...">
<data3>...</data3>
</otherData>
</data>
</dataCase3>
```

There could be many other variants of xml files.

Is it possible to bind all that files to java class using jaxb?

Comment: Yes, you can. Build packages for each xml-schema and bind them to your class.

Comment: Could you please describe it more detailed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [EclipseLink MOXy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics) implementation of JAXB to achieve this. As far as I understand, you will still have to create different classes for different types of schema but you can reuse your domain objects.

To continue with your example:

`DataStorage` class with 3 domain objects(`data1`, `data2`, `data3`), simplistically represented as `Strings`, can be really any JAXB mapped domain object.

- **Schema type 1**

  ```
  @XmlRootElement(name = "dataCase")
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class DataStorage {
      private String data1;
      private String data2;
      private String data3;

      /**
       * No-arg ctor needed by jaxb.
       */
      private DataStorage() {}

      public DataStorage(String data1, String data2, String data3) {
          this.data1 = data1;
          this.data2 = data2;
          this.data3 = data3;
      }

  }
  ```
- **Schema type 2**. Note the use of the [`@XmlPath`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlPath.html) annotation.

  ```
   @XmlRootElement(name = "dataCase")
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class DataStorage {
       @XmlPath("data/@data1")
       private String data1;
       @XmlPath("data/@data2")
       private String data2;
       @XmlPath("data/@data3")
       private String data3;
   ....
  ```
- **Schema type 3**. Again leveraging [`@XmlPath`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/oxm/annotations/XmlPath.html).

  ```
  @XmlRootElement(name = "dataCase")
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class DataStorage {
      @XmlPath("data/innerData/data1/text()")
      private String data1;
      @XmlPath("data/otherData/@data2")
      private String data2;
      @XmlPath("data/otherData/data3/text()")
      private String data3;
  ....
  ```
- **Marshalling**

  ```
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataStorage.class);
  Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
  DataStorage dataStorage = new DataStorage("data 1", "data 2", "data 3");
  marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
  marshaller.marshal(dataStorage, System.out);
  ```

See [this post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html) from the MOXy team lead's blog for me information.

Comment: +1 - You can also use MOXy's XML metadata file to apply multiple mappings to your domain model.  For an example see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838882/jaxb-annotations-extract-xml-value-from-xml-element

Comment: @Blaise That looks great. This will come in handy some time :)

Comment: Here is a more detailed example I put together demonstrating multiple mappings on a single object model:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use XSLT to translate your different XML formats into a single unified one.